# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {...} android.view.InflateException: (...)Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.CardView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-manifest, logcat

I have an app and after a splash screen, the app crash the time another activity is supposed to lunch, here is the logcat:

```
2020-07-12 12:25:13.360 19940-19940/com.Leenah.coloringbook E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.Leenah.coloringbook, PID: 19940
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Leenah.coloringbook/com.Leenah.coloringbook.Categories}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.CardView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.CardView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #28: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.CardView
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.appcompat.widget.CardView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.Leenah.coloringbook-eOxT7XNEkXXPvwnkz65RBg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.Leenah.coloringbook-eOxT7XNEkXXPvwnkz65RBg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:171)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:610)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:867)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:870)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
    at com.Leenah.coloringbook.BaseActivity.setContentView(BaseActivity.java:44)
    at com.Leenah.coloringbook.Categories.onCreate(Categories.java:51)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
    2020-07-12 12:26:08.311 19940-19972/com.Leenah.coloringbook E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval
```

And Here is the manifest file:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    
    <activity android:name="com.Leenah.coloringbook.MainActivity"/>
    <activity android:name=".BaseActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".Categories"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CategoryItems"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks, guys.

EDIT: A comment say that i should add the layout file where the card view is located, [so here is it](https://pastebin.com/sCD7Ds4q). (Its on paste bin cuz its so long and cuz it keeps saying the it looks like the post is mostly code.)

EDIT 2: Dependicies: https://pastebin.com/3UEBP3JL

Comment: Can you show the layout of the cardview ?

Comment: Can you share your activity's xml file?

Comment: Post your dependencies in build.gradle

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti https://pastebin.com/3UEBP3JL